# Python multiprocessing - return when fastest process terminates

Tags: python, dictionary, process, queue, multiprocessing

I've got a function f:

```
def f(param):
    return param**2
```

and a list of parameters p:

```
p = [1, 2092132192, 30912830921, 4102983092183]
```

(in my actual code, f POSTs to a URL specified in p and returns the response)

I want to call f on all items in p simultaneously and return the result that is the fastest and terminate the other three (or however many are still running) processes. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This kind of thing always seems to be notoriously hard.  If url fetching released the GIL (maybe someone else who knows the code better than I can comment on that), it seems like it might be slightly easier with threads than multiprocessing.  But even then, I'm not sure how I would accomplish it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this approach: Create a helper function which wraps `f()` and which doesn't return the result but puts it into a queue (maybe additionally returning it).

Now start the normal / usual process but don't wait for all threads to terminate. Instead, just wait for an item to show in the queue. If you get one, you can terminate the other threads and return.

Comment: `Queue.get(True, 60)` for waiting 60 seconds for an item.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to do this. What exactly does the wrapper function put into the queue?

Comment: `def wrapper(param): queue.put(f(param))`. I'm using a wrapper just in case you can't edit `f()` for some reason.

Comment: Figured it out a bit ago, but thanks anyway! I did this to kill all other processes: `for p in multiprocess.active_children(): p.terminate()` It's dirty but it works for now.